# Run multiple spring boot applications with different context paths under one port

Tags: spring-boot

Say, I've four spring boot applications A1, A2, A3 and A4. They all run under "/a1", "/a2", "/a3" and "/a4" context paths respectively. I want a single spring boot application which can run all these through just one server. So, I just created MainBootApp, whose @SpringBootApplication class has main method as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainBootApp.class)
                .sibling(A1.class, A2.class, A3.class, A4.class).run(args);
}
```

Just mentioning, MainBootApp has the dependencies of all the 4 projects in it.

I'm not sure if the approach is right for my requirement. I found this quite better because this gave me information of all the request mapping paths in all the four applications in the logs. But gives following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No parent defined yet (please use the other overloaded parent methods to set one)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.runAndExtractParent(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.sibling(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:247)
    at com.example.MainBootAppApplication.main(MainBootAppApplication.java:16)
```

Please help

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a standalone Tomcat installation, as opposed to embedded that's favoured by Spring Boot and already used by you. If your question is really about the URL and port layout, this requirement would be better served by putting a web server (like Apache or nginx) in front of your Spring Boot apps.